# Как прописать путь к txt-файлу?

Tags: c#, файлы

Как указать путь к файлу который находится в той же директории что и сам проект, то есть чтобы можно было этот файл и проект перекинуть в другое место и он все таки находил этот файл не меняя пути к нему? `FileStream f = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\TaskOne\input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`

Comment: проект или все таки исполняемый файл?

Comment: Папку с проектом, в которой находится файл.

Comment: можно получить путь до исполняемого и путь текущей папки, проект никак не связан с конечным исполняемым файлом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для это вам нужно оперировать двумя параметрами проекта Visual Studio:

- Working directory
- Output path

Возьмём для примера проект консольного приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Параметр `Working directory` определяет, какая рабочая директория будет задана по умолчанию текущему процессу консольного приложения.
Если этот параметр пустой, то рабочей директория будет директория из которой запущен exe файл. А его место создание определяется параметром проекта `Output path`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию это поддиректорий текущего проекта bin\Debug.

Таким образом, в данном случае, чтобы обратиться к файлу input.txt находящемуся в директории проекта нужно обратиться на два директория выше, т.е. использовать ".." в пути файла:

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(@"..\..\input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Так как пути все указываются относительно директории проекта, то при переносе папки проекта изменять пути не надо будет.

Директорией проекта является директория, в которой лежит файл проекта `.csproj`.

Comment: Начали за здравие, закончили за упокой. Ну нельзя обращаться к файлу "..\..\input.txt", при эксплуатации этот путь будет указывать незнамо куда!

Answer (score 0):

Включите файл в проект (если этого еще не сделано) и в свойствах укажите, чтобы он копировался в выходную директорию. Для английской студии это будет выглядеть вот так (а в русской все и так понятно):

[image]

В таком случае при настройках по умолчанию программа сможет найти его в текущей директории:

```
FileStream f = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: только при запуске из командной строки или какого-нибудь FAR или скрипта, этот файл может быть не найден. Чтобы заработало именно так, как вы написали, нужно еще и путь к рабочей папке назначить эквивалентным пути к исполняемому файл.

Comment: @rdorn тут уже все зависит от того, что это за файл. Если это внутренний файл для программы - то да, надо бы искать его относительно исполнимого файла. Но название файла подсказывает мне, что это - входные данные для программы. А в таком случае поиск в текущей директории становится уже не багом, а фичей - пользователь ведь будет, скорее всего, создавать этот файл где ему удобно, а не где программа лежит.

Comment: @rdorn тут, по-хорошему, надо бы еще имя файла принимать как аргумент запуска - но это уже следующий уровень.